# Declaring pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

When declaring a pointer in C, would ***(volatile unsigned char *)** be equivalent to just using **volatile unsigned char**? For example, would writing

```
#define myMemoryLocation (*(volatile unsigned char *)(12345678))
```

be the same as using:

```
#define myMemoryLocation (volatile unsigned char)(12345678)
```

Comment: What exactly is `*(volatile unsigned char *) `??

Comment: What does `*(volatile unsigned char *)` have to do with declaring pointers?

Comment: @ Sourav Ghosh. Please see my answer for a detailed explanation of what `*(volatile unsigned char *)` is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#define myMemoryLocation (*(volatile unsigned char *)(12345678))
```

is *not* the same as

```
#define myMemoryLocation (volatile unsigned char)(12345678))
```

The first treats `12345678` as an address in memory and evaluates to the value of whatever is stored there; the second simply casts the integer value `12345678` to `volatile unsigned char`.  You'd get very different results from the two.

Answer (score 3):

Let's analyze your first expression step by step

- You start with an int: `12345678`
- The cast `(unsigned char *)(12345678)` produces a pointer. This pointer points to a memory address 12345678. If you deference such a pointer you would get an unsigned char
- `(volatile unsigned char *)(12345678)` is the same pointer, but you are telling the compiler that the value of the memory location that this pointer points to can change "on its own".
- Then you dereference the pointer, so `*(volatile unsigned char *)(12345678))` is the value of the memory location 12345678 interpreted as an `unsigned char`. Because it is `volatile` the compiler must emit the code to read the memory location every time you dereference the pointer; it cannot cache the location in a register, for example.
- Finally, you give this expression a symbolic name `#define myMemoryLocation (*(volatile unsigned char *)(12345678))`

So every time you use `myMemoryLocation` in your program, the compiler emits the code to read an unsigned char from memory address 12345678

Now, let's look at your second expression. `(volatile unsigned char)(12345678))`. That's simply a constant expression. If unsigned char on your system is one byte long, it's value is always 0x4e (or 78 decimal).

clearly the two expressions are very different.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation! My original confusion was over whether adding the * before (volatile unsigned char *) would have caused the entire expression to stop being a pointer. Unfortunately, I had already accepted an answer before your post.

Comment: You are very welcome. We are all on SO to learn, help and broaden our minds. The other answer is correct, too, so no problem in accepting it.

Comment: This is a Nice Answer.